# Code needed to only show users own posts in a multi-user account

Tags: user-roles

I am using WP3 and want to starting adding users (many users to a single blog) but when I give a new user an account, they can see all the posts in the admin including scheduled, drafts, pending review etc. I either need the users to ONLY view their own posts or only view their own published posts (but not scheduled, drafts, etc). The admin should be able to see everything.

Here is a link I found on this issue with a code but the code is not working in my functions.php

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/show-only-authors-posts-in-admin-panel-instead-of-all-posts

Answer (score 6):

Put this into your *functions.php* file in your theme folder...

```
function query_set_only_author( $wp_query ) {
    global $current_user;
    if ( is_admin() && !current_user_can('manage_options') ) {
        $wp_query->set( 'author', $current_user->ID );
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'query_set_only_author' );
```

Comment: Great snippet, btw how can this be done only for custom post type?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here for a more complete solution (fixes the post count on the filter bar): [Help to condense/optimize some working code](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/34765/help-to-optimize-some-working-code-to-only-show-posts-of-logged-in-author-and-f)